# How do I align static "Right Detail" UITableViewCell contents with images properly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am using the storyboard, static cells and the "Right Detail" cell style. My issue looks like the following in both Xcode and simulator (red lines added for guidance):

[image]

As you can see, the third row is off. It is shifted to the right by 1 point. Both image and label are misaligned. All images have a width of 24px and the size inspector shows this correctly. Attributes inspector settings for all three cells are identical, except the image.

What's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the most likely explanation is that your "X" graphic isn't centered correctly.

If you've checked that it is correctly centered in photoshop, is it possible that the version you've checked and the one you are seeing in the app are different images (e.g. because one is a the @2x retina version)?

A good test might be to fill the background of the image with a colour (e.g. red) so you can see the image boundary and prove for certain that the image itself is misaligned, not the image contents.

Comment: Hi, I have access to the image in question myself and did a short check: All images are perfectly centered. To be more concrete: All images are 24px wide (non-retina), whereby the telescopre fills 23px and leaves off 1 px on the right side. The stopwatch leaves off 1px on either side. The "x" leaves off 5px on either side. All images differ in height. Retina versions have the same proportions as the non-retina images.

Comment: The fact that they are different heights may explain it. If the tableview is using AspectFit or equivalent for the image contentMode then the height might affect the horizontal layout. What happens if you frame all the icons with the same height?

Comment: Wow I think that has solved it. Will let @eteubert doublecheck the outcome.